# How to make a responsive "self cropping" background image?

Tags: css, image, background, responsive

I'm developing a wordpress theme and I'm having a bit of a problem.
In my homepage I want a wide background image with some text centered on it. So far pretty standard.
The thing is, I want the height to stay the same and as the browser gets smaller, the image should crop from both sides accordingly so the image stay centered.
Here is a great example I found, try resizing it and look at the big image at the top:
http://www.shopstyle.com/

How can I get this effect?

**Thanks in advance!** :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use property [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) with value `cover`, which was made for that purpose

> **cover**
>   A keyword that is the inverse of contain. Scales the image as large as possible and maintains image aspect ratio (image doesn't get squished). The image "covers" the entire width or height of the container. When the image and container have different dimensions, the image is clipped either left/right or top/bottom.

set the height you need (you can set different height for FHD, HD, Tablet, Mobile with media queries) and the image will be cropped from sides and zoomed if needed (if it's shorter than height you set)

Comment: Damn, that was simple!
Thank you so much! Sorry for being a noob!

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to using background-size: cover;

You should use view port height to control the height of the image. This way it will always be a certain percentage of the view port height, no matter if it's a desktop, laptop, phone, etc. It's the more fluid way to display a height.

Example (covers the whole screen):

```
.yourelement {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Example (covers half the screen):

```
.yourelement {
  height: 50vh;
}
```

Adjust accordingly.